# Cannot use psql "sudo: unknown user" "sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin"

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, postgresql, database

I've been working on a bot for Discord which utilizes a PostgreSQL database and I'm trying to install it on a Vultr server (Ubuntu 20.04). Everything is working fine until I get to the part where I'm trying to create the database inside the server and I've been trying to follow multiple guides on how to set it up, but whenever I try to run any postgres/psql commands such as `sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive` I get an error saying `could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied`

When I try to log into a user I've created by using `sudo -u araraura psql` I get errors saying `sudo: unknown user: araraura` and `sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`.

I've been at this for a day searching and looking for solutions on the internet, but I just couldn't find any solution that worked for me.

Comment: Are you logged in as `root` (via `sudo su` or `sudo -i` for example) when you try to execute the `sudo -u postgres ...` command?

Comment: Yes. I'm very new to Ubuntu, but I also know that it's an admin user by the `~#` in the command line. @steeldriver

Comment: So that's likely part of the problem - when you use `sudo -u postgres` from the `root` account, it's trying to access root's home directory as the non-root user `postgres`. Try `sudo -Hu postgres ...`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. I get the same errors as if I'm doing nothing different than before @steeldriver

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 20.04 version running postgresSQL 12 version and this is how is SOLVED:

- open the file `pg_hba.conf` in your favorite editor
- Example: `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf`

then you will see somethin like this:-

```
#local         DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#host          DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#hostssl       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#hostnossl     DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#hostgssenc    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
```

remove the # from the first line which un-comments the local, and replace with this below:-

```
local         all       all            trust
```

Local is how you manage Unix domain socket connections, now you can connect your database without password prompt and if you want to be asked password when connecting to database change the "trust" method to "md5", and run the following:

```
psql -U your_username db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

To login psql with new created user role,  you’ll need a Linux user with the same name as your new Postgres role.

To add the newly created user as linux user

- sudo adduser <new_user_role>